# how to use data sets or data source to inject data into my rule in drool-workbench?

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, drools-kie-server, drools-kie-workbench

I am new to drools . So I need help with developing my application.
My question is

1. What all the way to inject data into my rule(rule is available in  drools-workbench )
2. Is it possible to inject data into my rule from data-sets or data source (this 2 option is available drools-7.14 final version )

The main reason is I want to avoid java client (rest api)to supply data to my rule.
kindly help .